# По какой причине выделение даты не происходит(происходит только после переключения месяца туда - обратно)

Tags: c#, winforms

Пробую выделить определенные дни, но ничего не происходит в чём причина, пример брал с сайтов:

```
private void Data2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    monthCalendar2.Visible = true;

    if (monthCalendar2.Visible == true)
    {
        monthCalendar2.AddBoldedDate(new DateTime(2022, 6, 24));
        monthCalendar2.AddBoldedDate(new DateTime(2022, 6, 25));        
    }
}
```

Comment: интересная проверка на видимость, сразу же после `monthCalendar2.Visible = true;`, надеюсь это лишь в целях отладки

Comment: наверное, просто отрисовка не происходит сразу, попробуйте добавить `monthCalendar2.Update()`

Comment: @iKuzmychov, да, я пока проверял заметил, что выделение происходит, но только после переключения месяца туда- обратно, не знаете в чём причина?

Comment: @iKuzmychov, спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: @iKuzmychov, не помогло ( , добавил сразу после выделения

Comment: попробуйте ещё может `monthCalendar2.Invalidate()`

Comment: из MSDN: `monthCalendar2.UpdateBoldedDates();`

Comment: @из MSDN, спасибо заработало

Comment: какое из решений вам помогло?

Comment: @iKuzmychov, помогло monthCalendar2.UpdateBoldedDates();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/display-specific-days-in-bold-with-wf-monthcalendar-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#to-make-a-date-appear-in-the-regular-font) на MSDN, для отображения изменений, у календаря необходимо вызвать метод `UpdateBoldedDates()`.